# Parse.com API not sharing URL link (other data comes fine)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com give people an ability to share a URL from the app, to an individual "object" in Parse.com.

The below code works fine- EXCEPT for some reason the "LINK" (URL) is not coming through. All the other data comes through.

Is there a trick with Parse and sharing URL's?

My HTML is fine, I"ve pasted my javascript below.

```
var url = document.URL;

    var objectId = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    var name;
    var designer;
    var itemDescription;
    var price;
    var link;
    var image;

    Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");

    var garmentsAPI = Parse.Object.extend("garmentsAPI");
    var query = new Parse.Query(garmentsAPI);
    query.get(objectId, {
        success: function(garments) {
            console.log("success");
            name = garments.get("name");
            designer = garments.get("designer");
            itemDescription = garments.get("itemDescription");
            price = garments.get("price");
            link = garments.get("link");
            image = garments.get("smallImage1");
            $("#designer").html(designer);
            $("#name").html(name);
            $("#itemDescription").html(itemDescription);
            $("#price").html(price);
            $("#image").attr("src", image.url());
            $("#buyButton").attr('href', link);
            console.log(image.url());

        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            console.log("fail");
        }
    });
```

Comment: what r the parse datatypes of 'link', 'smallImage1'   ??

Comment: 'smallimage1' is a file, 'link' is a string

Comment: garments.get("link");   is this defined in the query result? if it exist for THAT Row on 'garments' as show in the parse browser, and if your current.User has ACL permission to read THAT row in 'garments' , then you should be OK

Comment: Where can I adjust individual ACL permission for each column?

Comment: ACL is for the entire row  .. check the docs

Comment: They all have public read/write for all rows. This must be a bug

Answer (score 2):

if your column name of file is

smallImage1 then

you can get url of file is as follows:

```
smallImage1._url
```